# Make temporary variable for vector?

Tags: c++

Which of the following is better? `vertices` is a `vector<vertex>`.

```
vertices.push_back(new vertex);
vertices[vertices.size()-1].name = name;
```

or

```
vertex v
v.name = name;
vertices.push_back(v);
```

I think the first is better because it doesn't do any extra copying, but the second is more readable, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Is `vertices` holding a `std::vector<vertex>` or `std::vector<vertex*>`, it's unclear from question?

Comment: in the first you are using vector<vertex *>, and it is `vertices[vertices.size()-1]->name`. Using pointers is way better.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant *not* using pointers is way better.

Comment: @user2079303: sure and calling the copy constructor each time you get/put an item is an optimisation ?? With a little structure it's fine, but if you have to override the copy constructor, not using pointers is just a waste of time, code, and performances.

Answer (score 2):

Both a bad (and `.push_back(new vertex)`) is especially bad (and it won't work with `std::vector<vertex>` because it returns pointer).

Here what you get:

```
vertices.push_back(vertex());             // construct temporary object
                                          // copy it to vector
                                          // destroy temporary object
vertices[vertices.size()-1].name = name;
```

vs.

```
vertex v;                                 // construct temporary
v.name = name;                               
vertices.push_back(v);                    // copy temporary object with a string
```

Assuming that copying string is not cheap, 2nd option is worse. However, if your compiler decides to apply [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) optimizations for the first case (which it is eligible to do since `vertex()` is a nameless temporary), then no temporary object would be introduced.

Cleaner solution came with C++11 which allow to construct objects directly in vector's memory without using temporary objects

```
vectices.emplace_back(/* vertex ctor parameters */);  // no temp objects here
vertices.last().name = name;
```

Comment: C'mon. It's 2016. No sane compiler will really create a temporary and destroy it in the first example.

Comment: @SergeyA, thanks for the note, I have forgotten about copy elision. Anyway, since it's 2016, there is no place for `push_back` :)

Comment: The "however" is a bit confusing because copy elision is exactly the reason why the 1st option is better. The second option can be made almost as good with std::move.

Answer (score 0):

Option one will allocate the vertex on the heap while option two will allocate it locally on the stack.

This really depends on your use case, we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

The two aren't exactly comparable. In (1) you are creating an object on the heap while the other is creating on the stack and copying to the vector (so yes you are making 2 copies). Really depends on your requirements and the context.

(1) would definitely take slightly more time due to heap allocation but it's a more persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the vector::emplace_back(Args...) method, which avoids any unnecessary copy's. 
If a constructor for a vertex exists that accepts some type of string argument for a name, that would be ideal. If it does not exist, i would highly recommend adding one just for this, as adding a new vertex with a specific name seems like a common operation.

```
vector.emplace_back(...,"My Name",...);
```

If no such constructor exists i would use the second method you listed. When using new like this `MyVector.push_back(new element)`, you will have to remember to delete it. On top of that, their is a possibility of a memory leak if an exception is thrown when the object is being constructed. If you really need to use the "new" method consider using an appropriate smart pointer.